# Why is there a null pointer exception error in my code?

Tags: java, linked-list

Why is there a null pointer exception error where `prev.value.compareTo(v)<0` and `if(cur.value.compareTo(v)<0` ?

```
public void insert (T v) {
        Node prev = head, cur = head.next;


        if(prev==null)
            {
            prev=head;

            }

        else if(prev.value.compareTo(v)<0)  //v belongs in the front
        {
            prev.value=v;
            prev=prev.next;
        }

        else
        {

            //iterate through the list
            prev=prev.next;
            cur=cur.next;
            while(cur!=null)
            {
                if(cur.value.compareTo(v)<0) 
                {
                    prev=cur;
                    cur=cur.next;
                }

            }

        }
}
```

Comment: In your code when `prev.value`  or `cur.value` is null, it can not have a method `compareTo`, so it cannot be called, as the object is null. You can only call `compareTo` when the object where it's defined is not null.

Comment: make sure that `value` is referencing an  object

Comment: This is where  debugger would be useful. I wonder about this code `Node prev = head, cur = head.next;


        if(prev==null)
            {
            prev=head;` If prev is null, head must be null so this doesn't do anything